# Android - Sending intent over mobile network

Tags: android, p2p

Essentially, I need to be able send an intent (or some other, basic data) from one phone to another over the mobile network. Is this possible? If so, how would I go about it?

I've toyed with the Wifi P2P for the past week or so, but I didn't realize that it was limited to around 100m. I'm trying to transmit data to anywhere in the world.

Maybe I would be able to send some kind of modified SMS, one that wouldn't register as a text message? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Why can't you go via a central server? Does it need to be p2p?

Comment: If you're asking, "Why don't I host a server?", I simply don't have those kind of resources. I'm fine with going through the mobile network (the carrier's towers, and whatever else they use to work).

Comment: I'd recommend looking into services like parse.com if you don't want to set up a server yourself. This will simplify things and save you having to figure out how to send messages p2p.

Comment: Hmm...looking at it, I'm not so sure that parse.com has what I need. The issue with it is that (with my app) the receiving phone is unaware when it's receiving, and parse.com seems like you would have to manually retrieve the data from the receiving phone.

Essentially, the receiving phone simply "listens" for a message, it can't request a message to be sent.